# BeautifulSoup not getting all Children elements

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Have an issue when trying to scrape the following URL: https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/lacteos/leches

I used the following simple code as a starter:

```
def Disco_scrape(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    main = soup.find_all("body")
    main2 = soup.find_all("div")
     
    return(soup, main, main2)
```

However, the vital info I'm looking for is in the main element inside body. I'm sending an image attached with the HTML code:
[image]

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Just for clarification: the children main element inside the body in the HTML code (which is in the image) is not being captured by BeautifulSoup. No idea why this is happenning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. However, the data is available via sending a `GET` request to the [API](https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/lacteos/leches?O=OrderByTopSaleDESC&_from=0&_to=23&ft&sc=1). For example, to print the item names, you can access the data as a Python dictionary (`dict`), with the `keys` / `values`.

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/lacteos/leches?O=OrderByTopSaleDESC&_from=0&_to=23&ft&sc=1"
response = requests.get(URL).json()

for data in response:
    print(data["description"])
```

Output:

```
Leche Entera UAT MANFREY Larga Vida 1 L
Leche Parcialmente Descremada UAT MANFREY Larga Vida 1 L
Leche descremada larga vida La Serenísima 1% 1 Lt
...
...
```

---

An alternative (slower) approach would be to use [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) together with `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the page.